# Add specific references at the end of the list overriding the order in which they are called

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I have a large project on beamer using biblatex for referencing. The references are given as numerals: [1], [2] etc. I have exported parts of the slides to PDF, which some colleagues have then exported to PPT to record speech. That means I can't change the current ordering of references anymore. The only thing I can do is add references at the end of the list, but instead they appear in the order they are called.

Is there a way to force biblatex to put specific references at the end of the list, regardless on when they are called?

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex` has the `presort` field for these sort of things. By default all entries are sorted as if their `presort` value is `mm`, so if you add a `presort` with explicit value you can make particular entries sort before or after all 'normal' entries.

By default the sorting scheme `none` does not account for `presort` because it sorts purely by occurrence in the text, but we can define a new sorting template that does use `presort`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=nonepre]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nonepre}{
  \sort{\field{presort}}
  \sort{\citeorder}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
  presort   = {zz},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{elk} % cited first, still sorts last
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{worman}
sit \autocite{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [4] ipsum [1] dolor [2] sit [3]]